# pagination not work if i change permalink for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

i have problem with pagination if i change permalink setting

i have created custom Template and in which i have display result and also apply pagination to display products. when i change permalink to postname then my url shows like this..

//localhost/traveller/root/2/ and pagination not work

and if i set permalink to default url like this...

//localhost/traveller/page_id=21/&page=2 and pagination work fine

pls suggest some solution to this??

I have used following code for pagination:

```
<?php
         $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
         $limit =5;
         $offset = ( $page - 1 ) * $limit;
?>   


        <?php $data = $wpdb->get_results("select * from table_name
                                          LIMIT $offset,$limit ");?>


                                       <?php
                                       $total=$wpdb->get_results("select * from table_name ");

                                        $pages = COUNT($total);
                                        $pages = ceil($pages / $limit);
                                        $querystring = "";
                                        foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
                                            if ($key != "page") $querystring .= "$key=$value&amp;";
                                        }


                                        // Pagination


for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
                {
                    echo "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"page active\" " : "class=\"page gradient\"");
                    echo "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$i";
                    echo "\">$i</a> ";
                }
                $page1=$page;
                $next=$page1+1;
                echo "<a " . ($i == $page ? "class=\"page active\" " : "class=\"page gradient\"");
                    echo "href=\"?{$querystring}page=$next";
                    echo "\">Next</a> ";

 ?>
```

Comment: We need to see your .htaccess. Also, please confirm this stuff is running on Apache and not Nginx.

Comment: @olaf:permalink change work for all pages but its only affected to pagination